# Data Not Rendering Using Next Js

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to use data from an API following the steps provided in the Next docs. My data does not render, this is my first foray into React so I'm not sure what I'm missing. Would somebody mind pointing out my error please?

```
export default function Home({ items }) {
  console.log(items) // Items listed in the console fine
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        <li key={index}>{item.description}</li>
      })}
    </ul>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  // Get Data Here
  return { props: {
      items
    }}
};
```

As you can see by my note above, the console lists the items as expected. I can also see the items array in the React Dev Tools in chrome.

---

The below console.logs as expected but again nothing is rendered to the browser.

```
export default function Home({items}) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        console.log(item.description);
        <li key={index}>{item.description}</li>
      })}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{items.map((item, index) => {
  console.log(item.description);
  <li key={index}>{item.description}</li>
})}
```

should be:

```
{items.map((item, index) => {
  console.log(item.description);
  return <li key={index}>{item.description}</li>
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need **return** in map function.

```
export default function Home({items}) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        console.log(item.description);
        <li key={index}>{item.description}</li>
      })}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

=>

```
{items.map((item, index) => {
  console.log(item.description);
  return <li key={index}>{item.description}</li>
})}
```